# Get Specific data from json services while populating List

Tags: android, json, list, hashmap

i need to populate a list view from data coming under the tag "group" from a JSON array "video". the coding under it is working fine if i remove  if condition. Please help me guys. My boss is kicking my ass for this and my job is on the line. thanks in advance

public class CountryJSONParser {

```
// Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

    JSONArray jCountries = null;
    try {       
        // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array 
        jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("video");
        } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
     // where each json object represent a country
    return getCountries(jCountries);
}


private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
    int countryCount = jCountries.length();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> country = null; 

    // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object 
    for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
        try {
            // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country 
            country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return countryList;
}

// Parsing the Country JSON object 
private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

    HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String countryName = "";
    String flag="";
    String language = "";
    String capital = "";
    String currencyCode = "";
    String currencyName = "";       

    try {
        countryName = jCountry.getString("Description");
        flag = jCountry.getString("thumbnailUrl");
        capital = jCountry.getString("title");
        language=jCountry.getString("group");
        Log.v("---","Country name: "+countryName+"Flag Url:"+flag+"Title"+capital);
            if(language.equals("RokuTest-VideoGroup")){     
        country.put("country", countryName);
        country.put("group", language);
        country.put("flag", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        country.put("flag_path", flag);
        country.put("details", capital);
        Log.v("---","Country name: "+countryName+"Flag Url:"+flag+"Title"+capital);
            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return country;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rohit.. Just manage the code in if and else block. It should work as you are saying removing if is working fine.

```
if(language.equals("RokuTest-VideoGroup")) {     
    // do somthing
 }
 else {
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: did you get any error in log cat?? can you give JSON response you are parsing?

Comment: Check the value of language, what it contains and print Log. And I would suggest to create separate class for JSON parsing. It seems when you use if block, condition got false and values could not be stored in country HashMap.